# Updating iOS through public WiFi in hotel

Tags: ios, software-update

Is it secure to update iOS when using public WiFi? Is there a chance the update is manipulated?

Comment: With hotel WiFi, security isn't the issue - the connection dropping out before completion would be bigger cause for concern. Wait til you get home.

Comment: The iOS upload is >2Gb in size, and as @tetsujin mentions, the hotel Wi-Fi may stop the upload due to data capping or just generic slowness. If you do want to give it a try, download an iOS speed test app and run a few iterations to see if the Wi-Fi connection is not only fast, but reliable. I use the **FCC Speed Test** (there are others) which measures Upload/Download speeds, along with with latency and loss. High numbers in upload & download is good; high numbers in latency and loss is bad.

Answer (score 4):

iOS updates are cryptographically signed by Apple - one among a [whole slew of integrity and security measures in iOS](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) (PDF document, see section "System Software Authorization").  If something modifies the update over the air, the update will fail to validate, and iOS will not apply the update.